unable to select the content outside of a model in react native
I'm developing a React Native app where I use a search bar to perform queries and display the results in a modal that opens directly below the search bar. The workflow I'm aiming for is as follows:
The user enters a query in the search bar.
When the user submits the query, a modal opens below the search bar, showing the search results.
The user should be able to interact with the search results in the modal or modify their search query in the search bar.
Problem:
Once the modal opens, I'm unable to click back into the search bar to edit or modify the search query. The modal appears to block interaction with the search bar, and touch events are not registered. Currently, the only way to edit the search query is to close the modal, make the changes in the search bar, and then re-open the modal by performing a new search.
Current Behavior:
After submitting a search, the modal opens correctly below the search bar, displaying the search results.
However, the modal seems to block interaction with the search bar.
To update the query, I have to close the modal, update the search query, and search again—reopening the modal each time.
Expected Behavior:
I want the search bar to remain fully interactive while the modal is open so that users can adjust the search query without closing the modal.
The modal should display the updated search results dynamically without requiring the user to close and reopen it.

I believe I understand your issue. The problem you're experiencing is that the modal, when open, prevents you from interacting with the search bar or any other component underneath. This is actually the intended behavior of a modal—it's designed to appear on top of all other components and block interaction with them until it's closed.
If I were in your situation, instead of using a built-in modal, I would create a custom modal using View components with position: absolute. This way, you can still have a modal-like appearance while retaining the ability to interact with the search bar and other components in the background.
Let me know if this solution helps or if you'd like further clarification!

yeah for now im using custom component only

Could you share the code?
